# Django 4.2 on AWS - collectstatic is not uploading files to S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

This has been a nightmare to try and figure out.  Nothing is working.  Here is my code.
eb-hooks log is always sending the files to the localhost

```
1084 static files copied to '/var/app/current/static'
```

Settings.py

```
USE_S3 = os.getenv('LOGNAME') == 'webapp'
CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN = 'https://d3g5b3y2rsspt8.cloudfront.net'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = env('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME')


if USE_S3:

    STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
    MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
    AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
    AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = True
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL =  None
    AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True
    AWS_QUERYSTRING_EXPIRE = 40000
    AWS_S3_VERIFY = True
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
    AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY_ID = env.str('AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY_ID').strip()
    AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY = env.str('AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY', multiline=True).encode('ascii').strip()
    MEDIA_URL = f'{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{MEDIAFILES_LOCATION}/'
    STATIC_URL = '%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN,STATICFILES_LOCATION)

    STORAGES = {
        "default": {"BACKEND": 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'},
        "staticfiles": {"BACKEND": 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'},
        "OPTIONS": {
            "bucket_name": AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
            "region_name": AWS_S3_REGION_NAME,
            "verify": AWS_S3_VERIFY,
            "signature_version": AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION,
            "cloudfront_key_id": AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY_ID,
            "cloudfront_key": AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY,
        },
    }
else:
    STATIC_URL = 'static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
```

The signed urls seem to be working, as when I go to the website, the urls are there, but exactly none of my static files are there.

EDIT:
When I click a link to a static url on my webpages, I am now getting a "access denied" error, "Query-string authentication requires the Signature, Expires and AWSAccessKeyId parameters"

My S3 policy resembles the one from the site  [Restricting access to Amazon S3 origin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": {
    "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipalReadWrite",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<S3 bucket name>/*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::<AWS account ID>:distribution/<CloudFront distribution ID>"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Edit 2: "no such key, The specified key does not exist." when trying to access the file from the website.
Again the URL seems fine. For example:

```
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>static/css/assets/bootstrap.min.css</Key>
```

Comment: 'This has been a nightmare' - what's this? what's happening here? you need to explain the context and problem more for us to be able to help you. what's happening and what do you expect to be happening instead? any links to any libraries you're using? what's 'on AWS'? Lambda? EC2? ECS? EKS?

Comment: It's an EC2 instance if that helps.  The S3 bucket is completely empty, I am running the collectstatic command from a postdeploy hook, which I have tested and it should work. So something must be wrong with these parameters.  I'm already aware that DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE and STATICFILES_STORAGE settings are deprecated for Django 4.2, and seems to be replaced by the storages dictionary (https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html)

Comment: You need to break down what `collectstatic` is for me please! and can you just edit the whole question to be "updated" to help us understand the problem in one reading? thanks

Comment: All of the info you need is there.  The files should not be saving to '/var/app/current/static' which is on the instance, it needs to save to the S3 bucket instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone using the latest Django 4.2 version this will be super useful, some things have changed substantially with django-storages, see the documentation for that.

Collectstatic is still not working to copy the files, but that's because if you have a lot of files, AWS is too slow to upload it, so it doesn't upload anything at all.  You have to upload everything manually.

```
USE_S3 = os.getenv('LOGNAME') == 'webapp'
CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = env('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME')
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY_ID = env.str('AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY_ID').strip()
AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY = env.str('AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY', multiline=True).encode('ascii').strip()


if USE_S3:
    STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
    MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
    MEDIA_URL = f'https://{CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN}/{MEDIAFILES_LOCATION}/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/static/{MEDIAFILES_LOCATION}/'
    STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN,STATICFILES_LOCATION)
    STATIC_ROOT = 'https://%s/%s/static/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN,STATICFILES_LOCATION)

    STORAGES = {
        "default": {"BACKEND": 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'},
        "staticfiles": {"BACKEND": 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'},
        "OPTIONS": {
            "bucket_name": AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
            "region_name": AWS_S3_REGION_NAME,
            "signature_version": AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION,
            "cloudfront_key_id": AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY_ID,
            "cloudfront_key": AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY,
            "custom_domain": CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN,
    },
}
else:
    STATIC_URL = 'static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, STATIC_URL)
    MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, MEDIA_URL)
```

Comment: The only thing that is not working with my signed URLs now, is serving them from CSS files, i.e. when using a url() link to an image within a CSS file.  The url comes out fine, but it's not signed!  Haven't figured out how to make that work yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add the following code into your `settings.py`:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = "static"
    default_acl = "public-read"


class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = "media"
    default_acl = "public-read"    

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'StaticStorage'
MEDIAFILES_STORAGE = 'MediaStorage'
```

and then run `python manage.py collectstatic` again. You can read more about it [here](https://testdriven.io/blog/storing-django-static-and-media-files-on-amazon-s3/) and [here](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/stable/backends/amazon-S3.html)

Comment: Signed urls look like the following: "https://*********-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/assets/bootstrap.min.css?Expires=1696820956&Signature=RfVcfS1vZoRw2xdGd7b3CJuiKZ4cevDS~icQ-o4MiSde2Hw557D1Ku-YUJcMP9HJ1jNZlsXThH6L2wwRVykRSSHMqeFSzWF0C9nvnwrFgMFACNteP5HVVmUd3yrEkHacwy82jjoDk2UVltdLMBdafEH~CU2hZbVDC5F4lnElzpqfv07NtDDVvnWqdUnhmgJODKTHfgewKxPu2pI3mwTz~EaYnGEpWCUaPR~HmXvgYv5ogt35E0B~KuA-166YUlQDE0UpS~RYs2JV8EY5-ZgLjQQaDtCoCbIs~I1GUIKsZW9fTPktMkixgnyuYwRSXZAQY~nw5rJ15nQ05-Xu2Sh8DQ__&Key-Pair-Id=K3**********"

What is missing is AWSAccessKeyId from the URL